# Link is not working in react-router-dom in version 5.3.0. Please anyone resolve this issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-dom, router

'Link' is not working properly. Please any one resolve this issue. I tried so many ways but non of them working. When I clicked on home or about, it doesn't move to other side, I have to reload the side manually.

Header.js

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
<Link className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to="/">Home</Link>
<Link className="nav-link" to="/about">About</Link>
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
<Router>
    <Header title="My Todos List" />
    <Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/"
        render={() => {
          return (
            <>
              <AddTodo addTodo={addTodo} />
              <Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete} />
            </>
          );
        }}
      ></Route>
      <Route exact path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
  </Router>
```

Package.json

```
{
```

"name": "todos-list",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},

Comment: Is the `<Header />` rendered inside of the `<Router />`?

Comment: Yes `<Header />` is rendered inside the  `<Router />`

Comment: I've put an example on sandbox with the same specifications you shared: https://codesandbox.io/s/changing-routes-react-router-dom-5-3-0-vwugjs 

One thing that I've noticed is that you're using the `Router` is this a reference to `BrowserRouter` or to anything else?

Comment: And I import **Link** in my Header.js file

Comment: could you edit the question and include your package.json as well?

Comment: I edit the question and include the package.json file..Please check

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This is the main issue I faced in React 18.

**You Can solve this problem in 2 ways**

**1. Move back to REACT version 16 and their react router dom version 5 works just fine**

[I used to react version 16 to solve this problem go to checkout](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-star-nv6uvx?file=/src/App.js)

**2. Upgrade your react router version 6 and use with React 18**

[Here is the code with react-router-dom version 6 if you want to see this code in action](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-brook-gjbsnu?file=/src/App.js:527-959)

My suggestion is to move react-router version 6 it's more powerful you can checkout docs.

**here Switch replace with Routes.**

```
 export default function App() {
  return (
   <Router>
    <Header title="My Todos List" />
    <Routes>
     <Route
      exact
      path="/"
      element={
        <>
          <h2>todo</h2>
          <p>deleteTodo</p>
        </>
      }
     />
     <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
    </Routes>
   </Router>
 );
}
```

Header

Also, use the Nav link for navigation to use the active class feature in react-router dom 6

```
function Header() {
 return (
  <header>
   <NavLink
    className={({ isActive }) =>
      isActive ? "active nav-link" : "nav-link"
    }
    aria-current="page"
    to="/"
   >
    Home
   </NavLink>
   <NavLink
    className={({ isActive }) =>
      isActive ? "active nav-link" : "nav-link"
    }
    to="/about"
    >
    About
   </NavLink>
  </header>
 );
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much dear, Now my code is working. I have no words to thanks you ..

Comment: I am using React-router-dom in Excel add-in development. But when I click on button to navigate, only URL changes, component does not switch. So what should I do

Comment: can you share the code or share the code editor link

Comment: I would recommend updating to React Router Dom v6 with React 18!